# jquery prevent loop

Tags: jquery, slideup

i have a hover slide down panel which needs a delay when mouse leave.
Like i have it now, hovering the trigger will result in multiple loops, so the panel goes crazy up & down.
Here is the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
(function(){
  var trigger = $('li.HotelPaneltrigger');
  var panel = trigger.find('.panel').hide();
    trigger.mouseenter(function(){panel.slideDown('slow');}).mouseleave(function(){panel.slideUp('slow');});
 })();
});
```

I tried this without success:
$(this).mouseleave(function () {
 $(this).delay('500')panel.slideUp('slow');

Comment: Any chance you can throw the full HTML & JS into a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if I get you right, but I think invoking `.stop()` will do it for you.

```
panel.stop(true, true).slideDown('slow');
```

and

```
panel.stop(true, true).delay(500).slideUp('slow');
```

Reference: [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `.stop(true,true)` before your `slideDown` and `slideUp` event should solve your problem, off the top of my head.